# Tooltips on SVG elements not appearing

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

Trying to code a map that shows a name on mouseover of an SVG element, and pulls up a modal on click. I just tried to add tooltips to display names as described here: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/tooltip/ but nothing is popping up and I'm unclear why. I changed all the variable names so they match my document. Here's the map: http://jsfiddle.net/gw5rmb1t/44/

The script I'm using is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 200" id="tooltip-svg-3">
<style>
    #tooltip {
        dominant-baseline: hanging; 
    }
</style>

<rect x="40" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#007bbf" class="tooltip-trigger"/>
<rect x="180" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#ec008c" class="tooltip-trigger"/>
<text id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden" >Tooltip</text>

<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var svg = document.getElementById('tooltip-svg-3');
        var tooltip = svg.getElementById('tooltip');
        var triggers = svg.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-trigger');

        for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mousemove', showTooltip);
            triggers[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip);
        }

        function showTooltip(evt) {
            var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
            var mouseX = (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a;
            var mouseY = (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d;
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "x", mouseX + 6 / CTM.a);
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "y", mouseY + 20 / CTM.d);
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
            var mouseY = (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d;
            tooltip.firstChild.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "fill");
        }

        function hideTooltip(evt) {
            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
        }
    })()
]]></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The example JSFiddle you posted has some errors (that I suspect are the source of your problems). In the browser console, I see the following error "svg.getElementById is not a function". This error is caused because in the JSFiddle the variable `svg` gets a `div` element, but in the example code in the question it gets a `svg` element.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean, but when I got rid of the div element, nothing happened. Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gw5rmb1t/60/. I really appreciate the help! I'm trying to learn to do this stuff but I think I'm too early on to even realize what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I only mention this since you that you're new and just learning, you may not know how to use the console for debugging. You can hit `F12` to open the browsers developer tools. One tab here will be titled "Console". Generally speaking, errors will be displayed here. If you want to output custom messages (or even whole objects!) to help with debugging, you can just write `console.log("blah")`. You can even use the developer tools to set breakpoints and step through your code line by line. Your latest fiddle still shows some errors, but I'm not familiar enough with JSFiddle to help

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much! I'll answer the question myself in the comments for reference in case it helps anyone else haha.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after working backwards from the original code and a tip from Vlad274, here's an answer in case it helps anyone in the future:

1. Got rid of the `div` tag
2. Added the line `<text id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden" >Tooltip</text>` in between the end of the elements in the svg and the script
3. In the script, set the `svg` variable to the `id` of the `svg`, the `tooltip` variable to 'tooltip', and the `trigger` variable to the class name of the map pins
4. Added a name attribute to each pin, and set:

   tooltip.firstChild.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "name");
               }

Here's the updated jsfiddle that works (the tooltips aren't formatted, but that should be easier): http://jsfiddle.net/gw5rmb1t/83/